# what book should I read to learn inferential statistics?

Tags: t-test, inference, references, group-differences

I am not a statistics student so I have no clue about inferential statistics. All I learned was descriptive stats. I am currently conducting research to find if two groups are similar/not. I have looked around and thought a paired t-test analysis would suit my research, as I have two groups, one of which I set as the control group. I am a bit confused because the examples provided on the internet are mostly about "before" and "after" conditions so I wish to read a book for detailed explanations regarding this paired t-test I'm  going to use. Please recommend an easy book to read for a beginner + easy to understand for a non-native English speaker.

Comment: So I am measuring the OTTV of several buildings and each of them are measured with different methods. I am looking for the difference in the usage of the the two methods.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a very broad request for books. Inferential statistics is an introduction topic and a hundred different books or resources could be suggested. A definite answer would be very difficult to formulate, but also a community wiki will not work well because of the large variation possible.

Answer (score 2):

*This question borderlines on an opinion question because it solicits opinions on texts that can be used to learn inferential statistics (which normally here would be off-topic). However, it seems the crux of your question is actually just determining which procedure to use for testing the differences between groups, so the bulk of my answer revolves around that.*

For this scenario, it appears a two-sample t-test (or independent sample t-test) would be the most ideal if you are just testing the differences between a control group and a treatment group (a categorical regression would also work essentially the same here). A paired t-test (or repeated measures t-test) is usually more for testing the same group measured at two time points. Importantly, a t-test only tests if one can reject the null hypothesis, $H_0$, which states that "there are no differences between the groups tested." Some would call this the "dull hypothesis" because we can neither accept the null hypothesis nor accept the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ (that there *is* a difference between groups) with a t-test that is statistically significant, nor do we get a magnitude of how different the group differences are. As that is the case, I recommend that when you do run a t-test that you include other important measures such as mean differences, effect sizes, and confidence intervals.

Since your secondary question is about resources for learning, the book *Learning Statistics with Jamovi* or *Learning Statistics with R* (both by Danielle Navarro) provide great introductions to statistics from a programming perspective (they are somewhat less math heavy though compared to other introductory books). I would also recommend *Essential Statistics for the Behavioral Sciences* purely for the math (which isn't difficult), but there are some inaccurate statements they make at times (such as $n > 30$ approaches normality) which make me hesitant to recommend it completely.